# TiKz and \pgfmathifthenelse

Tags: tikz-pgf

Does anybody know why, with the following code, I do not get my blue line go from (0,0) to (0.5,0)?

To me, the abscissa 1 should be multiplied by 0.5, given by `\pgfmathresult`, result of the condition `\pgfmathifthenelse` but that is not the case...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\origin}{
\node (O) at (0,0){$\times$};
\node at (1,0){$\times$};
\node at (O){O};}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\origin
\pgfmathifthenelse{1}{"0.5*"}{}
\draw[blue] (0,0)--++(\pgfmathresult1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: thanks for the welcome and your advice @Jubobs =) I take good note of it

Comment: Results of `\pgfmath*` operations are stored in the variable `\pgfmathresult` and you are not using it actually I don't know what should happen even if the syntax was right. Can you explain a bit what is the aim by editing your question?

Comment: you are right, I had forgotten `\pgfmathresult`. My bad. I have reedited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would definitely stay away from such usage but here the problem is that  `\pgfmathresult` defintion does not survive that long. So its current value needs to be used quickly. Because many drawing commands also use it internally.

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\mytemp{ifthenelse(1,"0.5*",)};
\draw[blue] (0,0)--++(\mytemp1,0);
```

works. Instead much more intuitive and also without any expansion-problematic code is

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\mytemp{ifthenelse(1,0.5,1)};
\draw[blue] (0,0)--++(\mytemp*1,0);
```

This also equivalent to

```
 \draw[blue] (0,0) --++({ifthenelse(1,0.5,1)*(1cm)},0);
```

[image]